# Why isn't my blender .fbx file exporting to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, export, blender, fbx

I am trying to export an blender .fbx file to Unity(it is a mesh with a simple animation), but when I export and I open my Unity Project it will show a "HOLD ON..." screen. I tried to force quit unity and open it again, I was able to see the file BUT it wasn't rlly working I couldn't use it. Can anyone tell me what to do to make it work?

Comment: What version of Unity3d and Blender are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version blender 2.8 and unity 2019.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution to my problem. So instead of exporting from blender to unity, I imported it from Unity
(but the color or material of the object wasn't imported)